# React Local Storage to target previously selected buttons

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, local-storage, styles

Each button changes color when pressed. And I want them to stay that color every time the page reloads until a a localStorage.clear() is ran.
So I'm trying to re-apply the previously applied css with local storage. My idea is to store the Ids of each button, loop through Ids, and re-apply css. But it keeps throwing error: "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')". Another issue I seem to have is I lose my local storage on the 2nd page reload!
If you have a way to improve this or a better way to go about this please let me know! Thanks.

****UPDATED Code**** 
Here is a link to the most working version
https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-rui-vz7tf?file=/src/App.js
I added a "Delete History Btn".
The only issue now is after a reload and selecting another button, the local storage is completely erased with the new selection. What I need is the selections to stack until the user runs a localStorage.clear().

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';


      const App=()=> {
  const [btns, setBtns] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('BtnsClicked', JSON.stringify({ btns }));
  }, [btns]);


  const handleAcknowledge=(event)=>{
    setBtns([...btns, event.target.id])
  
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "red"
    event.target.innerHTML = "Clicked!"
  }

  const reSelectBtns=()=>{
    const storedBtns = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('BtnsClicked'));
    
    if (storedBtns.btns.length){
      storedBtns.btns.forEach(btn=>{
        console.log(document.getElementById(btn).style.backgroundColor = "red")
    })
  }
  }
  reSelectBtns()

  return (
    <div className="App">
     
      <button id = "1" onClick={handleAcknowledge}>Acknowledge</button> 
      <button id = "2" onClick={handleAcknowledge}>Acknowledge</button> 
      <button id = "3" onClick={handleAcknowledge}>Acknowledge</button>  
      <button id = "4" onClick={handleAcknowledge}>Acknowledge</button>  
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please share a minimum reproducible example to debug the local storage clearance on reload.

Comment: this is a reproducible example. There's nothing else to it.

Comment: Here it is on codepen,
https://codepen.io/chasemillers/pen/xxXQpBw?editors=0011

Comment: Here is a better codepen by lokprakash https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-wood-bz2g3?file=/src/App.js:792-812,
The only issue now is after a reload and selecting another button, the local storage is completely erased with the new selection. What I need is the selections to stack until the user runs a localStorage.clear().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this sandbox link of mine https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-marco-7wgon?file=/src/App.js

It addresses your problems.

Comment: Sorry still have same error.

Comment: I have edited my answer. It is working with the new code which I edited. Verified through code sandbox example. https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-wood-bz2g3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Many blessings upon you! Thank you!

Comment: Okay so there is still a strange issues were it seems to be ignoring previous selections, or skipping a selection. For example, If I select all, reload, then click one again, it erases previous selections on the next reload?

Comment: So, I see the issue, 
The first selection is stored perfectly. But after a reload and selecting another button, the local storage is completely erased with the new selection. What I need is the selections to stack until the user runs a localStorage.clear().
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hey, I added a new sandbox link. Check it out. It is solving your problems. https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-marco-7wgon?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could upvote your answer 20 more times.